# Synchronise user input during cross-browser testing

Tags: testing, cross-browser

Are there any tools available that allow user input to be synchronised between browsers during manual cross browser testing?

For example, mouse clicks, data entry into a form etc.

*Information:*

*This sort of functionality was described by Mads Kristensen in a recent [DotNetRocks podcast](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=927). He outlined a BrowserLink extension he had created (around 11:00) that demonstrated this during a recent talk. However I'm unable to find any other reference to it, and would like to know if any other alternatives exist.*

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain how you mean 'synchronise'? As in, it needs to happen on each browser at exactly the same time? Or you just want a consistent set of data used and the timing to be the same for each test?

If the latter, I'd suggest looking at something like Selenium WebDriver. I know this is more automated, but you can't get something exactly consistent if you're doing it manually.

Comment: Unfortunately I do mean the former. My ideal scenario would be to have 4 browsers open across maybe 2 monitors, and any user input (mouse clicks, key presses etc) be carried out in one and replicated in the other 3. Hope this clarifies what I mean.